# Interrupt is sometimes adding two (repeated) elements to array instead of one

Tags: c++, interrupt

Im trying to write code that records LED's when a button is pressed, stores them into an array, and when that array is 5 long, it stops cycling through LED colours and plays the recorded pattern. It sometimes works perfectly, however sometimes it will double record a single button press/led colour. I can't figure out why. If anyone could let me know any possible issues it would be much appreciated :).

Here's the code (C++):

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include <vector>

// Green LED
DigitalOut led1(LED1);
// Blue LED
DigitalOut led2(LED2);
// Red LED
DigitalOut led3(LED3);
// Button Interrupt
InterruptIn button(USER_BUTTON);
// Initialise counter for button presses (n), and selector for the lit LED (l)
int n = 0;
int l = 1;
// Define sequence length
int sequence_length=5;
// Create vector/list for recorded LED's to go into
int sequence[5];

// Callback function to associate with the press button event
void onButtonPress()
{  
    led1 = true;
    led2 = true;
    led3 = true;
    // Add corresponding led to 'sequence'
    sequence[n] = l;
    n = n + 1;
}

// 'Decoding' what LED's should be lit up for different 't' values in main
void select_led(int l)
{
        if (l==0) {
                led1 = false;
                led2 = false;
                led3 = false;
        }
        else if (l==1) {
                led1 = true;
                led2 = false;
                led3 = false;
        }
        else if (l==2) {
                led1 = false;
                led2 = true;
                led3 = false;
        }
        else if (l==3) {
                led1 = false;
                led2 = false;
                led3 = true;
        }
}

int main() {
    // attach the address of the callback function to the rising edge
        button.rise(onButtonPress);
        while (true) {
            while (n >= sequence_length) {
                select_led(0);
                wait(1);
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    select_led(sequence[i]);
                    wait(0.5);
                    select_led(0);
                    wait(0.5);
                } 
            }
            select_led(l);
                wait(1);
                l = l + 1;
                if (l==4) {
                    l = 1;
                }
        }
}
```

I'm not sure if its a logic issue or if its dependent on the length of the button press, or another unconsidered factor.

Comment: I don't recognize `InterruptIn`, but if it is just a plain old interrupt and there is no denouncing happening, you will get that result at times.

Comment: My guess is debounce. You either implement debounce as a low-pass filter on the input, the GPIO has built-in hardware debounce, you specify timed debounce on the GPIO, or you implement a software debounce in your own code. I don't know what chip you're using or your board, so I can't answer any of those questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably has to do with the way you press the button. If there is even a little hesitation the button will recognize two presses and not one. Try adding a `wait` to the end of the `onButtonPress` function in order to account for this occurrence.